# Rails compare Time with TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time

In my Rails app, I'm comparing a `date` from my database to `Time.now`:

```
Event.date_start >= Time.now
```

But `Event.date_start` is  `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`

Everything works perfectly but I want to know if comparing a `Time` with a `TimeWithZone` is the proper way, and if this is not the case, how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time.now` also works with `TimeZone`. Look at this:

```
Time.zone.now
#=> Mon, 12 Sep 2016 16:51:54 UTC +00:00

ExampleModel.date_start
#=> Tue, 28 Jun 2016 12:39:26 UTC +00:00

Time.zone
#=> #<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x0055de104e3ce0 @name="UTC", @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Etc/UTC>, @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: nil,nil,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: 0,0,UTC>>>>
```

You can compare this without restrictions :)

Answer (score 10):

The best practice is not to use `Time.now` in Rails apps. Use `Time.current` instead. It returns `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`  too.

Comment: Thanks. `Time.current` use `config.time_zone` in **config/application.rb** ?

Comment: `Time.current` is same as `Time.zone.now` :)

Comment: exactly @BartekGładys, but it adds less ABC noise (1 vs 2 method invocations) :)

Comment: Okay and `Time.zone.now` use `config.time_zone`. Thanks ;)